# Webservice image public url

Tags: php, .htaccess, frameworks

I have done a custom php framework with this folder hierarchy:
[image]

Now I have a class ApiController for webservices with json response.
One of my api methods, getAvatars, have to return a list of avatar with public url of images in the uploads/images folder, but this folder is restricted from access by the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
# Send request via index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I create a link like example (in localhost): "localhost:5000/uploads/images/avatar_1.png" accessible outside of my application for all of my images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your .htaccess

< Directory /uploads >

Options +Indexes